# LWC Array Sorting in Wire

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, html

Feel like this is probably a new developer mistake, but I am trying to sort an array of selectable record types displayed in a lwc picklist. Whenever I try to sort the array, the order does not actually change. Just going for alphabetical ascending. Anyone able to assist?

```
 @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    accObjectInfo({data, error}) {
        
        if(data) {
            let optionsValues = [];
            // map of record type Info
            const rtInfos = data.recordTypeInfos;

            // getting map values
            let rtValues = Object.values(rtInfos);

            for(let i = 0; i < rtValues.length; i++) {
                if(rtValues[i].name !== 'Master') {
                    optionsValues.push({
                        label: rtValues[i].name,
                        value: rtValues[i].recordTypeId
                    })
                }
            }
            
            this.recordTypeOptions = optionsValues.sort();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, objects can only be sorted with a sort callback.

```
optionsValues.sort((a,b)=>a.label.localeCompare(b.label));
```

The function should return -1 if a is less than b, 0 if equal, and 1 if a is greater than b. These values are used to determine if a should come before b in the list.

This particular example presumes every level will have a value. Additional code will be necessary if this is not true.

Edit: I really should stop writing code on my phone...

Comment: U da best! :) Marked!